# iPad pro simulator: black screen on full resolution

Tags: ios

My app has a strange behavior in iOS-simulator: If I scale the simulator to 100% I can only see the navigationbar and a black screen. If I scale down to 75% or below the view gets visible - no error in console visible. Scaling up to 100% again switches back to the black screen.

Any ideas? Is it working on real devices?

I'm using Xcode 7.2 and iOS9.

Comment: Have you used the horizontal and vertical scroll bars that appear on the Simulator screen when the simulated screen is larger than your computer display?

Comment: where can I set those?

Comment: If I rotate the device, at least the cells from my collectionview become visible sometimes.

Comment: You don't have to set them -- they just appear when you hover the mouse near the edges of the window

Comment: Yes they appear. Everything is ok on other screens within my app